# Create PDF from Firefox

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, firefox

I am looking for options to create a PDF from webpages in Firefox, under Windows 8. I have found a ton around, but few appear to satisfy my list of requirements:

1. Free to use (not just free to try)
2. Simple to use
3. Not using an online service
4. Without bundled software, in particular, those often deemed as adware/spyware.

The best options that I found so far are:

1. FoxIt PDF reader + Printer, although it "bundles" the reader, from the standpoint of the priner.
2. Add-on *Print pages to pdf*. I used it, and I found it pretty decen. But it was removed by the author. **EDIT**: It might be available [here](https://addons.palemoon.org/extensions/other/print-pages-to-pdf/) (not tested).

---

**Various notes (may be skipped if avoiding *tl;dr*)**:

PS: it would be interesting to know whether the solutions proposed are tested, in particular commenting on requirement 4. For instance, CutePDF is a candidate, but in that case, it would be interesting to know *from experience* which specific version does not bundle software, or has an option for not installing it which actually works as intended.

PS2: of course, pointing to *related questions* is welcome. It would be interesting in those cases to know if there are actual solutions to this OP.

PS3: Please, prior to marking this OP as a dupe (which I think it is not), check carefully if my requirements are really the same. Solutions proposed to different questions may be suitable here, but this does not make the OP a dupe.

Comment: Presumably by operating offline you mean not using a web conversion - if you are truly offline then there will be not pages for firefox to save. Also which OS may make a difference.

Comment: @SteveBarnes - 1) Offline: that is what I meant. And you could be truly offline, and have pages already loaded in FF, which you want to print while offline. 2) OS: Windows. I fixed both points for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: I want to *disrecommend* [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/download). In it's newest version 2.1 it includes thy trial-software [*PDF Architect*](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfarchitect) and I haven't found an option to not install it along with PDFCreator

Comment: I have just found [*PDF It!*](http://www.touchpdf.com/pdfit.jsf).
It is an Add-On, it seems to do the trick, similar to *Print pages to pdf*.

Comment: @nixda  Did you goto control panel **Programs and Features** and just uninstall **PDF Architect**?  It is listed.  Uninstalling it afterwards is relatively simple.

Comment: @cybernard Of course. But it bugged me that I had to do this. They (PDF Creator) also bundled some other software where they offer an option to uncheck it. But not this one

Comment: @nixda - I have installed in the past PDFCreator, and it installed the pdfforge toolbar. I could not uninstall it completely (including all associated pieces of code, services, etc.), and this difficulty was documented at many sites. I think that there was a nominal way of removing it, which did not actually work as a full removal. Take this with a grain of salt, as I am mentioning what I remember. So the warning is: An *Uninstall* may not always really Uninstall. Software bundled with PDFCreator is possibly one such case.

Comment: Some ideas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_virtual_printer_software Most free virtual PDF printers come with crapware

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of Windows print to pdf drivers for Windows, including:

- Windows 10 has native support, *some might consider the whole OS adware/spyware though, LoL*, To activate the feature, simply navigate to the Windows 10 Settings page and click on Devices. *When setting privacy you need to set it in settings **and** in every browser*
- I have used [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) writer in the past and it has worked well, been advert and watermark free, (from the main site), but you do need to install [GNU Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) *again from the main site*.

Comment: I am using Win 8 (I have now made this explicit in the OP). CutePDF might contain adware, see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-best-tools-print-pdf/ and http://www.malwareremoval.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=63064&sid=ac9c1e23a3596df384d43349a386a35d&start=0. I am not sure which version (if any) is completely free from code other than that needed for the functionality of CutePDF.

Comment: See: http://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=cutepdf.com - this is for downloads from the _main_ site - as mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). Basically, it creates a virtual printer to which you send your documents (in your case, a webpage) to "print", and it creates a PDF out of it. It fulfills your requirements.

Note: user @nixda reports (comment on the OP question) that latest versions include unwanted software. Older versions work fine for me. You could give it a try.

Comment: Could you please specify which version are you using, which does not have any additional software (e.g., pdfforge toolbar)?

Comment: It's v1.2.3.  I refrained from updating exactly for these reasons.

Comment: I have just launched the installer of 1.2.3. It installs the PDFCreator toolbar (there is no option for not installing), which is sort of spyware. I cancelled installation

Comment: 1.2.3 is not safe, apparently. Check https://www.mywot.com/en/forum/3256-pdfcreator-www-pdfforge-org-is-causing-havoc-with-toolbar-install, and http://www.mularien.com/blog/2009/03/24/sourceforge-hosted-pdfcreator-trojantoolbar-warning/

Comment: Strange, I have no such toolbar in any of my browsers, and I don't remember PDFCreator installing it or me removing it manually. By the way, have you tried uninstalling the toolbar from the Firefox Add-ons menu?

Comment: i think that, even if you do not have the toolbar, you likely have services and/or other program/s (besides PDFCreator) launching at startup.

Comment: I interrupted installation, so I do not have a toolbar to uninstall.

Comment: I've checked my system startup and it does not contain any additional strange process that might have been inserted by PDFCreator. Cf. your second comment, it was supposed that you completed the installation of PDFCreator (so you could try afterwards to uninstall the toolbar from the browser's add-ons menu).

Comment: Hands on the PDF creator is the best alternative. I have used it for years. there is always an option for not installing the toolbar.. just be attentive while going forward with the installer.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen - The option for not installing the toolbar is not available for all versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [NovaPDF](http://www.novapdf.com/) before and it worked well for my needs.  It's on my system now, but I don't use it much.

It's another PDF printer; you didn't say if you wanted a printer or a Firefox extension.  I haven't updated it in a really long time, but when I installed it, it did not come with any unwanted extra programs.

Comment: I think it is not free.

Comment: Any of the two is ok.

Comment: Yes it is a shareware.

Comment: I haven't paid for it.  Though I've only used an older version.  I wonder if the license model has changed over time...

Comment: What version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Bullzip PDF printer for many years.  The interface isn't fantastic, but I've had very few problems and at least when I got it, it was free with all the functionality I wanted, and didn't come with any crapware.  I'm using version 10.7.0.2277.

Comment: Could you please specify which version are you using, which is free from additional software?

Answer (score -1):

I have just found [*PDF It!*](http://www.touchpdf.com/pdfit.jsf).
It is an Add-On, it seems to do the trick, similar to *Print pages to pdf*.
It seems to meet the 4 requirements in the OP.

Cons: As far as I could test, there is no way of generating a pdf with actual text (to copy, e.g.) It is only an image.